# Loading PHP RRDTool extension not showing PHPinfo

Tags: php, rrdtool

I downloaded 5.5 Thread Safe (TS) x64 from http://pecl.php.net/package/rrd/1.1.3/windows

Because I'm running Wamp 64bits PHP version 5.5.12 TS enabled
from that folder I only took php_rrd.dll file and placed it on ext/ and loaded the extension on the php.ini file that shows phpinfo(). But, the extension does not show at phpinfo(). Is there something that I'm missing?

i also placed the following files on /bin/php5.5.12 folder

1. cairo.dll
2. expat.dll
3. fontconfig.dll
4. gobject-2.dll
5. pango-1.dll
6. pangocairo-1.dll
7. pangoft2-1.dll
8. pangowin32-1.dll
9. pixman-1.dll
10. rrdlib.dll

I also tried placing this files on system32 and still nothing.